# hidden component when using jquery.splitter with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, angularjs

I'm trying to use https://github.com/vorburger/jquery.splitter, a relatively standard jQuery plug-in (it draws a splitter between two DIV), with-in AngularJS, [see my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n8vMxs?p=preview), but somehow the Splitter seems to disable (hide) AngularJS.. why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your plunker and it seems that its ok. Only plugin parameters are not correct. I tried them with other parameters but same for calling it from outside and inside the directive.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qTn9xl

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.run(function(){
  $('#splitter1').width(20).height(40).split({orientation:'horizontal', limit:10});
});
```

You should call plugin initialization from inside the angular app so that if angular doesn't work then none of them will get initialized. So Angular is not getting disabled. Its just configuration of jquery.splitter is not correct.